# Respring after installing tweak from Cydia

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia, tweak

I made application and mobilesubstrate tweak using Theos by DHowett. Tweak is a subproject of application. I tested it on my iPhone, everything works fine. Then I made a Cydia repo and loaded my project to it. The problem is when I installing my application-tweak from Cydia, it doesn't respring my iPhone. It just showing button "Return to Cydia". So I have to manually respring my iPhone to make it work.
I've got 2 control files in each project, I suggest that I have to change them somehow, but I don't know how:

**Application' control:**

```
Package: com.espe.dualtime
Name: DualTime
Depends: mobilesubstrate
Version: 1.0.3
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: Dual time zone for lockscreen
Maintainer: Danis Ziganshin
Author: Danis Ziganshin
Section: Tweaks
```

**Tweak's control:**

```
Package: com.espe.tweak
Name: tweak
Depends: mobilesubstrate
Version: 0.0.1
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: An awesome MobileSubstrate tweak!
Maintainer: Danis Ziganshin
Author: Danis Ziganshin
Section: Tweaks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I were suppose to add `Depends: mobilesubstrate` to the Packages.gz file in the repo. After that I've got respring after installation.