# Creating Cydia Logos Tweak, now required respring after installation (How to do)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia, tweak, logos

I am creating a Logos Tweak for Cydia and i did complete my task, but now i required "Restart SpringBoard" after Installation.
Can anybody tell me what i have to do to achieve this like many apps in Cydia store, In which after installation button appears with text "Restart SpringBoard" instead of "Return to Cydia".

Comment: Take a look [at this](http://insanelyi.com/topic/5799-how-to-writecode-preinst-postinst-prerm-postrm-scripts/) or [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9596410/119114)

Comment: thanks kindly write your answer in answer section so that i can mark it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this 2 ways if you are using [THEOS](http://github.com/dhowett/theos/),

First one (if you do make clean then you will have to redo these steps),

Create 2 files in the DEBIAN folder which is located in `mytweak/_/DEBIAN/`
Call them `preinst` and `postrm`
Inside those files paste:

```
declare -a cydia
cydia=($CYDIA)

if [[ $1 == install || $1 == upgrade ]]; then
    if [[ ${CYDIA+@} ]]; then
        eval "echo 'finish:restart' >&${cydia[0]}"
    fi
fi

exit
```

Then run `make package` to create the new package that has the respring button on it

The second way is much more simpler and can be used without theos,
In the `control` file which is located in the `DEBIAN` folder, you should know where this is.
Add the line:

`Depends: mobilesubstrate`

Credit to [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119114/nate) for this answer, although I did know this.

Hope this helped.