# How to make Cydia ask for Respring?

Tags: cydia

I just made a repo via myRepoSpace.com, but notice when I install my app from Cydia it doesn't ask to respring the device, instead it says "Return to Cydia" on the button, how do I make it say "Respring Device"? Is there something I need to do with my app? At present I have to come out of Cydia then respring my device before my app works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [using iPhones](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe I need to add some code to my app?

Comment: Found the answer here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207364/creating-cydia-logos-tweak-now-required-respring-after-installation-how-to-do

Answer (score 0):

If its a tweak you can simply just add Depends: MobileSubstrate to the control file, or if its an app, you shouldn't really need to respring, but if the app icon wasn't appearing just run this in postinst

```
uicache
```

This will just clear all caches and refresh your SpringBoard Icons.